# Compare two Lists using Linq for partial matches

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I tried looking through some of the other questions, but couldn't find any that did a partial match.

I have two `List<string>`

They have codes in them.  One is a list of selected codes, one is a list of required codes.  The entire code list is a tree though, so they have sub codes.  An example would be
Code B
Code B.1
Code B.11

So lets say the Required code is B, but anything under it's tree will meet that requirement, so if the Selected codes are A and C the match would fail, but if one of the selected codes was B.1 it contains the partial match.

I just need to know if any of the selected codes partially match any of the required codes.  Here is my current attempt at this.

```
//Required is List<string> and Selected is a List<string>
int count = (from c in Selected where c.Contains(Required.Any()) select c).Count();
```

The error I get is on the Required.Any() and it's cannot convert from bool to string.

Sorry if this is confusing, let me know if adding any additional information would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<string> selected = new List<string> { "A", "B", "B.1", "B.11", "C" };
        List<string> required = new List<string> { "B", "C" };
        var matching = from s in selected where required.Any(r => s.StartsWith(r)) select s;
        foreach (string m in matching) {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Applying the `Any` condition on `required` in this way should give you the elements that match - I'm not sure if you should use `StartsWith` or `Contains`, that depends on your requirements.

Comment: Works great, thanks for the help.  I've been at this so long today my brain as turned to mush and I just kept staring at this thing trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If selected and required lists are large enough the following is faster than the accepted answer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> selected = new List<string> { "A", "B", "B.1", "B.11", "C" };
    List<string> required = new List<string> { "B", "C" };
    required.Sort();
    var matching = selected.Where(s =>
    {
        int index = required.BinarySearch(s);
        if (index >= 0) return true; //exact match
        index = ~index;
        if (index == 0) return false;
        return s.StartsWith(required[index - 1]);
    });
    foreach (string m in matching)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
}
```

Given `n = required.Count` and `m = required.Count` the accepted answer algorithm complexity is `O(n*m)`. However what I propose has a better algorithm complexity: `O((n+m)*Log(n))`

Comment: Very good one, +1! I didn't know what BinarySearch returns in case there is not a match (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx), thanks.

Comment: Yes!. Unfortunately SortedDictionary doens't provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This query finds any match that exists in two lists. If a value exists in both lists, it returns `true`, otherwise `false`.

```
List<string> listString1 = new List<string>();
List<string> listString2 = new List<string>();

listString1.Add("A");
listString1.Add("B");
listString1.Add("C");
listString1.Add("D");
listString1.Add("E");

listString2.Add("C");
listString2.Add("X");
listString2.Add("Y");
listString2.Add("Z");

bool isItemExist = listString1.Any(x => listString2.Contains(x));
```