# How to find elements from 1 collection which partially matches elements in a second collection?

Tags: c#, linq

**The Question**: Given 2 collections where 1 collection partially matches some of the elements in the second collection, how can I identify items in the first collection which do not make any appearance in the second collection?

**Sample Input & Desired Output**:

`files` has 230 elements. A few samples:

```
"C:\Some\Dir\My_File_01.ext"
"C:\Some\Dir\My_File02.ext"
"C:\Some\Dir\My_File3.ext"
"C:\Some\Dir\MyFile4.ext"
```

`names` contains 25 elements. Samples:

```
"_01"
"e02"
"File_03"
```

`desiredOutput` should contain 1 element: `"File_03"`. We do not want `"_01"` because that matches the tail end of the first element of `files`. I do not want `"e02"` because that too exists in the second element of `files`.

**My Attempt**:

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710311/compare-two-lists-using-linq-for-partial-matches) but am having difficulty modifying the statement to work for me. This is what I have:

```
var matching = from f in files where names.Any(n => !f.Contains(n)) select f; // returns 230 elements
```

I also tried:

```
var matching = from n in names where files.Any(f => !n.Contains(f)) select n; // returns the original set of 25 elements from names
```

And a third modification:

```
var matching = from n in names where files.Any(f => !f.Contains(n)) select n; // also returns the original 25 from names
```

I also looked at [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx), but since none of the elements between the two are identical it won't work for my purposes.

Comment: Matching rule(s) is unclear. Can you specify them explicitly?

Comment: var matching = names.Where(name => !files.Any(file => file.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())));

Comment: @sab669 Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var matching = names.Where(name => !files.Any(file => file.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())));
```

[Working demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sbSv1k)

Comment: Brilliant, and I was not aware `dotnetfiddle` was a thing! Love it. Thanks.